# Unsound null safety without upgrading legacy packages

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

My app has a lot of legacy library (e.g. [EPUB](https://pub.dev/packages/epub), [EPUB_KITTY](https://pub.dev/packages/epub_kitty)) which does not support Null Safety yet and the authors are already inactive.

I've read that we can mix non null safe library and null safe library by adding // @dart=2.9 at the main or adding
`--no-sound-null-safety` during build.

So first I've updated my sdk in pubspec.yaml into:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

then I've also updated all of the dart files to support null safety.

and the build command I ran is:

`flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

But i've encountered errors with path_provider: ^1.6.11:

```
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+1/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.3/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);  
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

I thought this is because of null safety but it should not show that error right? since I was using the --no-sound-null-safety command? Anyways,  I've upgraded the path_provider into `path_provider: ^2.0.2 (latest null safety version)` to see if it would fix the problem but after building I've encountered another problem about dependency incompatibility, so I've updated the old packages again to fix the incompatibility problem but eventually I've reached the point where the error is about the EPUB package as describe below:

```
Because image >=3.0.1 depends on xml ^5.0.0 and epub >=1.3.0 depends on xml >=2.6.0 <4.0.0, image >=3.0.1 is incompatible with epub >=1.3.0.

So, because testco depends on both epub ^2.0.0 and image ^3.0.2, version solving failed.
```

What should I do about this? The author of this package is already inactive so should I fork the epub package and update the xml library version manually to fix the build error? or is there a way to solve this without updating the epub package internals? Please advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the package, you will see that there is an issue opened about null-safety.

While the author has not replied and seems inactive for years, people have *forked* it and this fork was updated to null-safety.

https://pub.dev/packages/epubx

You have to test whether this meets your needs. If it doesn't, consider helping them or forking it on your own.

The same goes for every other package. Check their issues page, see if other people had the same problem and maybe it was fixed or they fixed it on their own. If there is no issue about null-safety, you should maybe look for a different package alltogether, because that means nobody is using it but you.